# How to solve the sum of three digit numbers,with how to calculate the second number

Tags: c, sum

```
once = number/100;

thenth = (number%100)/10;

hundred = number%10;

sum = once + thenth + hundred;

printf("Sum of entered digits is %d\n", sum);
```

how the second number is calculated ex.(345%100)/10=34.5 how to calculate 2nd number please can anyone explain the logic of this program

Comment: Integer division results in integers, and the floating part is truncated.

Comment: Just study what each equation does.  It will be obvious to you what is happening.

Comment: theth and the hundred is giving me the same answer i am not able to getting the logic 34.5

Comment: _theth and the hundred is giving me the same answer_: Cannot reproduce, please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @h.pankaj 345%100 = 45/10 = 4  Do you understand it now?

Comment: thanx really helpful thank for saving my time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(number % 100)`, for a non-negative `number` extracts the final *two* digits, and dividing that by `10` will effectively discard the unit digit due to *integer division*. So it's a scruffy way of calculating `thenth`.

You can solve this more elegantly by lopping off the least significant digit of `number` as you go:

```
hundred = number % 10;
number /= 10;
tenth = number % 10;
number /= 10;
once = number;
```

Hopefully, the ability to roll this into a loop to solve a more general case is now obvious.